# Split Column with Differing Lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to split out a cell into multiple columns with differing lengths (some have one additional field while others will not). I also have additional data in other columns so I'd like to maintain my dataframe structure while doing this. Any ideas?

Code:

```
d = {'Product':product, 'Description':description}
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
raw_df[['Company', 'Location', 'Stock', 'Description', 'Price', 'High']] = raw_df.Description.str.split(expand=True)
```

Sample Data (this is one cell needed to be split by /n):

```
Company Name
6221 - Jacksonville, FL
Total Stock
This is a description
$400
$999
```

Error:

```
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Expected Output (notice the NaN):

```
        Company          Location        Stock            Description Price  High
0  Company Name  Jacksonville, FL  Total Stock  This is a description  $400  $999
1  Company Name  St Louis, MO      Total Stock  This is a description  $400  NaN
```

Comment: what is in your input dataframe? can provide reproducible.

Comment: This error comes when after split you are getting additional split elements than the mentioned ones. you can limit it by using  `apply`--> `df['a'].str.split('\n', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x[:6], axis=1)`

Comment: You have given `6` columns in `raw_df` but your data `Company Name` is having only `5` rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pandas.DataFrame.str.split` method splits string on whitespaces by default ([see the docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)). So if you want a different delimiter you need to specify it, such as

```
raw_df[['Company', 'Location', 'Stock', 'Description', 'Price', 'High']] = raw_df.Description.str.split('\n', expand=True)
```

And it looks like you are overwriting the `"Description"` column, so maybe you'd like to change its name or you could just assign this split to a new DataFrame, such as

```
df = raw_df.Description.str.split('\n', expand=True)
df.columns = ['Company', 'Location', 'Stock', 'Description', 'Price', 'High']
```

Either way, your output will like like you wanted

```
        Company                 Location        Stock            Description Price  High
0  Company Name  6221 - Jacksonville, FL  Total Stock  This is a description  $400  $999
```